# Keycloak JWT Validation C#

Tags: .net, authorization, keycloak

i'm trying to validate a JWT generated by keycloak and used by the frontend (React) to authorize certain calls in my API server (.NET).

.NET version: 6.0
Keycloak version: 23

This is the code i use to validate it in my startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication(opts =>
            {
                opts.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                opts.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
 .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:8080/realms/my_realm";
                options.Audience = "client-id"; // same client used by the frontend
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {

                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:8080/realms/my_realm",
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                };
            });
```

but it returns

```
Connection id "0HMVQAE7SLA72", Request id "0HMVQAE7SLA72:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application. System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'. 
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync() 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync() 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler1.AuthenticateAsync() 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme) 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitMatcher|8_0(EndpointRoutingMiddleware middleware, HttpContext httpContext, Task1 matcherTask) 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication1 application)
```

This works if the server is executed locally (Windows) with keycloak in a docker container, but not if both keycloak and the .NET Server are dockerized.
Any suggestions to fix this error?

Comment: Have you tried changing 'localhost' to the container name and put both container in the same network? If they run in two separate container, localhost means the container the .NET application is running inside, since every container is equal to a machine.